# How to get the original Path part of a non well formed Uri in C#?

Tags: c#, uri

I'd like to get the original Path and query component for the following 2 Uri-s:

```
https://example.com/folder1/something?param%5Fvalue=abc%20def
```

should result:

```
/folder1/something?param%5Fvalue=abc%20def
```

and:

```
https://example.com/folder1/something?param_value=abc def
```

should result:

```
/folder1/something?param_value=abc def
```

I tried `Uri.PathAndQuery` and `GetComponents(UriComponents.PathAndQuery, UriFormat.Unescaped)` methods, but they are failing in at least one of the 2 sample Uris.

I know that these sample Uris are not well formed, but they are based on "real" examples, so not just a theoretical question.

I'd like to avoid string manipulations.

Comment: What do you mean by _"they are failing in at least one of the 2 sample Uris"_?  Can you elaborate on how its failing?

Comment: @haldo: It does not return the expected string.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  I was asking exactly how it does not return the expected string.  Can you provide and example of the expected result and the result you actually see?

Comment: @haldo: But the samples are in the question. Ok, the actual result is missing, but you can try that...

Input:https://example.com/folder1/something?param%5Fvalue=abc%20def
Expected:/folder1/something?param%5Fvalue=abc%20def
Actual1:/folder1/something?param_value=abc%20def
Actual2:/folder1/something?param_value=abc def

Input:https://example.com/folder1/something?param_value=abc def
Expected:/folder1/something?param_value=abc def
Actual1:/folder1/something?param_value=abc%20def
Actual2:/folder1/something?param_value=abc def

Actual1 is PathAndQuery
Actual2 is GetComponents